# How to split a pyspark dataframe based on a column value

Tags: pyspark, split, partitioning, dynamic-columns

I have a below sample data frame.So the data from first roll no to mobile number is data of a student and the data from next roll no to email is data of some other student. And so on. In nut shell I am getting  dynamic data for students.(everytime I will have roll no for sure)

```
 **Column**       **Value**
Roll no      141641
Name         SUNNY
Mobile     4567892345
Roll no     141633
Name        Vikas
Email      V.com
```

Now I am trying to slice the data into different data frame based on column Roll no ,and data should look like this

DF1

```
Column         Value
Roll no      141641
Name         SUNNY
Mobile     4567892345
```

DF2

```
Column      Value
Roll no     141633
Name        Vikas
Email      V.com
```

And then final data should like

```
Roll No   Name    Mobile   Email
141641   SUNNY 4567892345  Null
141633  Vikas  Null       V.com
```

Any idea how can we achieve this in py-spark.

Comment: how do you know that the data is sorted From Roll No? With that in mind, what if Vikas appears before Sunny? Spark dataframes are unordered. Do you have any ordering key?

Comment: The data I am having is like ,first I will have data of first student and then data of second student and so on. Actually I have prepared this data from a json file ,which will give me data like what I have just mentioned. Let say if Vikas comes first then I will have first row for vikas in the dataframe

Comment: Do you have a student id column in the json Or dataframe? If yes, please include that in the question